# Excel cell value remaining after being cleared

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to clear certain cells in an excel file, but when it clears them the value remains. When I click on the cell value disappears but I need it to do it once the cell is cleared in the code. Edit: As requested, more code. The cells still do not empty until I have clicked them even with setting the value to empty as suggested.

```
Private Sub Update(Target As Range, EventTarget As Range)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim CurrDevice As String
Dim CurrPort As String
Dim ConcatInfo As String

CurrDevice = Range("B" & Target.Row).Value
CurrPort = Range("C" & Target.Row).Value
ConcatInfo = CurrDevice + CurrPort

Dim TargetRange As Range
Set TargetRange = Range("R2:R" & EventTarget.Row - 1).Find(ConcatInfo, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not TargetRange Is Nothing And Not TargetRange.Row = EventTarget.Row Then
    'Range("F" & TargetRange.Row, "P" & TargetRange.Row).ClearContents
     Range("F" & TargetRange.Row, "P" & TargetRange.Row).Value = Empty
    End If
End If

Set TargetRange = Nothing
Set TargetRange = Range("R" & (EventTarget.Row + 1), Range("R" & (EventTarget.Row + 1)).End(xlDown)).Find(ConcatInfo, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not TargetRange Is Nothing And Not TargetRange.Row = EventTarget.Row Then
    'Range("F" & TargetRange.Row, "P" & TargetRange.Row).ClearContents
    Range("F" & TargetRange.Row, "P" & TargetRange.Row).Value = Empty

End If

Exit Sub
```

ErrorHandling:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: Show more code, what you have shown is not causing the problem.

Comment: As mentioned, nobody can really help you without a lot of assumptions since you have not shared the relevant code here

Comment: You start with `Application.EnableEvents = False` then at the end you have `Exit Sub; ErrorHandling:; Application.EnableEvents = True; End Sub` You're exiting the sub before you enable the events. If, somewhere else in your code you have a workbook or worksheet event that includes `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` then you're shutting off the screen updating and never turning it back on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Worksheets("NameOfWorksheet").Range("A" & 1, "Z" & 10).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Then slowly change `1` and `10` with `TargetRange.Row` and see whether it works. The `TargetRange` should be defined as range like this:

`Dim TargetRange as Range`

and set to some range like this:

`Set TargetRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A19")`

Answer (score 0):

To clear a cell, you can assign it as Empty:

```
worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = Empty
```